# What's the nuances when using "modicum"? Can I say "a modicum of coffee"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I came across this word ***modicum***, which seems a fancy way of saying *a little bit*.
What's the nuances when using it?
Can I say "a modicum of coffee"? -- I usually order latte with tiny amount of coffee, since I'm caffeine sensitive.

I tried searching on the internet, didn't find it around this kind of usage.
Any suggestion or discussion on this is welcome, thanks in advance :)

Comment: "Just a modicum of sugar helps the medicine go down." --Mary Poppins

Comment: @DjinTonic  Thanks! That's a great example of its usage :-)

Comment: I think @DjinTonic is being facetious; the line is "a spoonful of sugar". I can't recall "modicum" ever being used for solid physical objects (though perhaps I haven't heard it enough). I usually hear it in phrases like "a modicum of quiet". A quick web search confirms: modicum of support, relief, attention, interest, power, courage, etc.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan- you’re making an interesting point. Modicum is mainly  associated with abstract concepts rather than physical things. Modicum of sugar, though, appears to be an exception https://www.google.com/search?q=%22modicum+of+sugar%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1956%2Ccd_max%3A2019%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=XLmxYZzPEtK1sAf_mYroDw&oq=%22modicum+of+sugar%22&gs_lcp=Cg9tb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXNlcnAQA1AAWABgzCxoAHAAeAGAAZ8OiAHfG5IBAzgtMpgBAKoBGW1vYmlsZS1nd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAtbW9kZXPAAQE&sclient=mobile-gws-serp

Comment: OED has quite a few literary examples with food like "a modicum of honey" (Unsworth) or "a small modicum of dry toast" (Trollope); not sure if this is slightly humorous or poetic.

Comment: I would avoid "modicum". It sounds very old-fashioned and gives the impression of someone using a rare word when a perfectly common word would be normal - it is inappropriate in most circumstances for those reasons.

Comment: @Greybeard  Got it, thanks for your advice :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=102996952) for `modicum of *`. Here's the list of nouns that had 3 or more results:

> respect, privacy, control, dignity, stability, success, intelligence, justice, effort, security, sense, peace, order, decency, comfort, civility, relief, education, hope, knowledge, interest, discretion, protection, support, talent, trust, truth, understanding, research, decorum, cooperation, credibility, fame, grace, independence, normalcy, respectability, restraint, safety, sanity, wealth, sympathy, time, skill, wisdom, water, self-respect, science, shame, social, light, pride, prosperity, pressure, inquiry, integrity, happiness, courage, courtesy, deterrence, empathy, evidence, exercise, confidence

It's a list of almost entirely abstract items. And when I looked at the hits for "water", I found that all three referred to water as a utility (including one use that used it as an attribute noun: water flow).

The usage you want would not be common as I couldn't find a similar example even among the lower-frequency results.

(Modicum as a loose unit of measure did have some usage a long time ago, as [COHA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/?c=coha&q=103000005) indicates. Most bizarrely, I was able to find an example of "a modicum of eggs". Alas this is wording from a bygone era.)

Instead, you can call it a "splash of coffee":

> Where there are no judgements for adding a splash of milk- or just a splash of coffee! — [Cohesive Coffee](https://www.cohesivecoffee.com/about-us)

Comment: There is a curious spike in usage from about 1880-90 for *sugar* in the Ngram and a recent uptick for *normalcy*, but with such low frequencies, these could be just a few more instances.

Answer (score 0):

**modicum** (n.)

> *In singular* A small quantity of a particular thing, especially something considered desirable or valuable.
>
> *It's done in a spirit of fun, and relies on a modicum of good faith*
> among the participants.’[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/modicum)

> A small quantity or portion; a moderate or limited amount. (Often
> modified by little, small, tiny.)
>
> Of food, drink, or the like.
>
> 1992   B. Unsworth *What I generally have at this time of
> afternoon..is a syllabub of cream and thin cider, sweetened with a
> modicum of honey.*
>
> Of money or other property.
>
> 1990   Amer. Rifleman  *Those DCM juniors we select can expect a
> travel allowance from their home to Fort Benning and back, housing and
> a modicum of spending money for meals.*
>
> *gen*. (chiefly of immaterial things).
>
> *Pract. Photogr.*—*Pictures taken with just a modicum of
> imagination.* OED

> QUANTIFIER  A modicum of something, especially something that is good
> or desirable, is a reasonable but not large amount of it.
>
> [formal]
> *I'd like to think I've had a modicum of success.*
> *...a modicum of privacy.* [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/modicum)

> **modicum** (plural modicums or (rare) modica)
>
> A modest, small, or trifling amount.
>
> Etymology From Late Middle English *modicum*, borrowed from Latin
> *modicum* (“a little, a small amount”), a noun use of the neuter form of
> *modicus* (“moderate; restrained, temperate; reasonable”) + -*cum* (suffix
> forming neuter nouns). *Modicus* is derived from *modus* (“a measure; a
> bound, limit”) (ultimately from Proto-Indo-European **med*- (“to
> measure”)) + -*icus* (suffix meaning ‘of or pertaining to’ forming
> adjectives). [OUP cited]
>
> The plural form *modica* is derived from Latin *modica*.
>
> 1988, Terry Gilliam; Charles McKeown, The Adventures of Baron
> Munchausen, spoken by Baron Munchausen (John Neville):
> *I have learned from experience that a modicum of snuff can be most efficacious.* [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modicum)

---

*Modicum* appears in a few book titles, e.g., [Armando Heredia; *An Artist of Modicum Success*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Artist_of_Modicum_Success/Nc3iDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=An%20Artist%20of%20Modicum%20Success&printsec=frontcover). (2016)

> Whether or not matter claimed to be a trade secret "possesses at least
> that **modicum** of originality which will separate it from every day
> knowledge" is a question of fact which must attend the trial. [Roger
> Milgrim; *Milgrim on Trade Secrets, Vol. 1*](https://www.google.com/search?q=modicum&tbas=0&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvJ4WeNfSzhPnOBNvOjUmUyPifONDQ:1639050108844&ei=fOuxYeawMqCoqtsP5rOHsAo&start=30&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjm3oW80db0AhUglGoFHebZAaYQ8tMDegQIARBC&biw=1089&bih=508&dpr=1.25) (1992) (Snippet View)

> From these data it appears that following perturbation, and once the
> soil has developed some cover sufficient to provide shade and deposit
> a **modicum** of litter, it becomes less acidic and aluminum content
> decreases. [S. Darwin and A. Welden; *Biogeography of Mesoamerica*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Biogeography_of_Mesoamerica/iMMTAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=modicum&dq=modicum&printsec=frontcover)
>  (1992)

> Moreover, they brew this Chinese herb with boiling water and then sip
> the hot infusion to benefit their health, and when the infusion verges
> on being too bitter, the well to do may add a **modicum** of sugar.
> [George van Driem; *The Tale of Tea*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Tale_of_Tea/Z6WODwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22modicum%20of%20sugar%22&pg=PA323&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

For whipped cream in my hot chocolate, I prefer *dollop*. Collins uses the label *formal* for its *modicum* examples. I agree with Stuart F's comment that some of the examples give a wry wink, and  with Greybeard's that it can sound old-fashioned. Note that there were *no* comestibles among Lexico's many examples.

Comment: Yeah I checked wiktionary too, guess I better avoid using it like that. Still it's an interesting wordplay :-)